# Typed event bus service - TypeScript

Tags: angular, typescript

I'm trying to write an event service for some angular application. Currently, it looks like this:

```
import {EventEmitter, Injectable} from '@angular/core';
import {Subscription} from 'rxjs';

type EventHandler<P> = (payload?: P) => void;

/** List of available event types */
export enum EventType {
  GENERAL = 'GENERAL',
  ADD_SOURCE = 'ADD_SOURCE'
}

interface Emitters {
  [key: string]: TypedEventEmitter<any>;
}

class TypedEventEmitter<Payload> {
  private readonly emitter = new EventEmitter<Payload>();
  subscribe(handler: EventHandler<Payload>): Subscription {
    return this.emitter.subscribe(handler);
  }
  emit(payload?: Payload): void {
    this.emitter.emit(payload);
  }
}

/**
 * This. service is used to allow components to emit and subscribe to events.
 * Each event has its own Subject, to enforce its payload type.
 */
@Injectable({providedIn: 'root'})
export class EventService {
  private readonly emitters = {
    GENERAL: new TypedEventEmitter<string>(),
    ADD_SOURCE: new TypedEventEmitter<void>()
  };

  publish(type: EventType, payload?: any) {
    this.emitters[type].emit(payload);
  }

  subscribe(type: EventType, handler: EventHandler<any>): Subscription {
    return this.emitters[type].subscribe(handler);
  }
}
```

Now, I want the consumers of this service to be aligned with the types of event emitters that exists in the this.emitters variable.

For example, if someone wants to subscribe to EventType.GENERAL, I want it to be aligned with its payload type, which is a string. In other words, if he'd try to do something like this:

```
eventService.subscribe(EventType.GENERAL, (payload: number) => {
  console.log(payload);
})
```

He will get an error, saying something like "number is not assignable to string".

The problem is, I don't know how to enforce it. How can I workaround this issue?